# How to add class with @resource annotation from a dependancy JAR to spring-boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i have  two projects one for cache and other to use it. I have added the dependency of cache project as jar in my spring-boot application. but the classes mentioned with @Resouce i am not able to access in my spring boot application. how to resolve it?

Comment: If you are taking about dependency injection, add `component` scan with base package of dependency jar

Comment: not really. I have two distinct applications consider app A and appB. App A ia already created and is having class named @resource. I want to use it in 2nd application. i added app A jar in App B but its not picking up resource class to use in AppB I have added component scan correectly.

Comment: Have you checked whether Spring bean got created for @Resource annotated class, you can check using `/beans` acctuator endpoint

Comment: @Resource annotated classes are not creating .. that is the issue